# Which local groups beside Local Administrator allow elevating privileges to administrator on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, administrator

> Which local groups beside Local Administrator allow elevating privileges to administrator on Windows 10?

To ensure that local users cannot elevate their privileges to administrator solely by using their local group memberships, I want to audit local group memberships (e.g. Local Administrator.)

Are there other local groups that can be used to easily elevate privileges to administrator? If so, how?

Comment: “Are there other local groups that can be used to easily elevate privileges to administrator?” - No; Only the Administrator group exists y default.  Unless you create your own custom groups with the same access.  Strictly speaking you could give a normal user elevated permissions but you would be fighting the default permissions if you did that.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Maybe off-topic, but how would you create your own elevated groups, or give a normal user elevated permissions?

Comment: Definitely out of scope for this particular question

Comment: @Ramhound I would like to ask a new question regarding giving a normal user elevated permissions, but I don't know how to ask it. Please provide a resource.